# Is it possible to disable onclick without altering its function?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

The way I know to disable an `onclick` event on an element is:

```
element.onclick = null;
```

To enable:

```
element.onclick = function(){
   // something
};
```

or

```
element.addEventListener("click", me);
```

This is fine but when you have several elements - each of whom has the same function with different parameters value - it becomes a bit annoying to use this way. Is there a way I can disable it without sacrificing the initial function with its parameters?

I want to keep the function the way it is without having to set it to null or to something else in order to disable.

Comment: Take a look at the observer pattern [Book](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript)

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're looking to achieve.. are you looking to overide the global method ?

Comment: No I just want to disable the onclick, but keeping the functions, without having to set the function to null

Comment: can't you just define the function elsewhere?

Comment: Return null and stop the propagation of your event

Comment: @Michael I could but that will cost time, as it is define in the server side.

Comment: Declaring a function, and then setting it as the function for onclick of an element is no more time consuming than declaring the function within the onlick assignment

Comment: @Alexis I have point it out that I can disable by simply returning null. but thats not what I intent to do, I came here to ask if there is another way to do this without having to modify the functions

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `disabled` attribute to disable a button.

```
<button onclick="alert('clicked')">Enabled</button>
<button onclick="alert('clicked')" disabled>Disabled</button>
```

The advantage of this method (over the "pointer events" suggested in an alternative answer) is that it will not only stop you using the button as a mouse user, but will also stop assistive technologies and anyone using the keyboard.

In JavaScript, you can disable or enable the attribute with:

```
el.disabled = true;   // Disable.
el.disabled = false;  // Enable.
```

Or with jQuery you can do:

```
$('button').prop('disabled', true);   // Disable.
$('button').prop('disabled', false);  // Enable.
```

Comment: Its fine approach but I need to stop keyboard too, or I cant use it, but thanks for the answer I voted up

Comment: @luke i think he is saying that this method will disable keyboard users, compared to the other answer (with pointer events), which won't

Comment: @DonCruickshank: Since I also misunderstood the answer, I have edited it to make it more clear. Feel free to revert or improve if you disagree.

Comment: @Heinzi Yes, I see how that makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in css.

```html
<button onclick="alert('clicked')">Can click</button>
<button onclick="alert('clicked')" style="pointer-events: none;">Cannot click</button>
```

Pro: it works on all HTML elements

Con: it doesn't prevent keyboard action

Comment: This will stop someone using a mouse to click the button but it will not stop keyboard users from being able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
<button onclick="false && alert('clicked')">Try Click (Disabled)</button> 

<button onclick="true && alert('clicked')">Try Click (Enabled)</button>
```

It will work for both click event and keypress event.

```html
<button onclick="false && alert('clicked')">Try Click (Disabled)</button>

<button onclick="true && alert('clicked')">Try Click (Enabled)</button>
```

Comment: @luke it will stop both key and click event from calling the function without doing any change in the script.